# Can I make grain-free noodle/ravioli/dumpling dough?

Tags: noodles, gluten-free, dumplings

I'm celiac and I'm intolerant to virtually all the grains (also to corn/maiz). So, the question is if I can make noodle/dumpling dough without grains?

Yuca and potato starch are good for me, also chickpea and other legumes are fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you source glucomannan(also called konjac root & may also appear as pounded yam flour)? How about methyl cellulose?  Can you do teff or quinoa?

Answer (score 3):

You could look into cellophane noodles. They're made from starch (often yam or potato), so it sounds like they'd work for you.

If you have a decent Asian grocery store around, you may well be able to just buy them, too. You'll just have to be careful to check the ingredients, as they are sometimes made with corn starch too. (I'm not sure if it's whole corn or even the starch that you can't have.)

Comment: And when looking through Asian groceries -- you might see bags of noodles in water, typically under refrigeration.  They're shirataki noodles, which are made from a variety of yam.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can be done. [Jamie Oliver](http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/pasta-recipes/gluten-free-pasta-dough) is a good place to start. Here's a collection of recipes by celiac cooks [Celiac.com](http://www.celiac.com/categories/Gluten-Free--Recipes/Gluten-Free--Recipes..--Noodles--____--Dumplings-c-3411). Plus, check out this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=gluten+free+potato+dumplings) and this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=grain+free+potato+dumplings).

I don't have any personal experience cooking grain/gluten free, but I may be going back to Iowa soon. My cousin there is celiac, so I'd love to hear how this goes for you. I'd enjoy cooking dinner for my cousin.

Comment: The Jamie oliver link has both rice and corn flour/starch which would be excluded given the OP's dietary restrictions.